# How to access the node title within a field template?

Tags: 8

I'd like to know the node title within the file link template. How can I get it?

For the current example I use the bootstrap `file-link.html.twig` template. In it, I have the following variables:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a link to a file.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: The HTML attributes for the containing element.
 * - link: A link to the file.
 * - icon: An icon.
 * - icon_only: Flag to display only the icon and not the label.
 * - icon_position: Where an icon should be displayed.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\bootstrap\Plugin\Preprocess\FileLink::preprocessVariables
 */
#}
```

I dont know if a preprocess function is the correct way to go. I didnt even found a respective hook for drupal 8 for that. I dont even know if this is a field template. But still, the question would also be interesting for other templates than file-link.

Answer (score 4):

He wants to get the node title in the file link template (I assume that is `file-link.html.twig`). 
You can implement the hook `template_preprocess_file_link()` in your mytheme.theme file, get the current node and pass its title to twig, something like:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_file_link(&$variables) {
   $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
   $variables['node_title'] = $node->getTitle();
}
```

Then, in `file-link.html.twig`:

```
{{ node_title }}
```

Comment: does not work some reason, but I will continue testing

Comment: @Alex did you try the last edit? the initial answer had typos

Comment: @Alex I think that it should work. Did you try some debugging in php and in twig?

Comment: wouldnt it be cleaner to get the node from the variables?

Comment: @Alex I didn't tested exactly the code. If you have the node in $variables, use it. I f not, use `$node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');` to get the current node.

Answer (score -2):

I assume, you are using Drupal 7 and we're talking about a node.tpl.php:

```
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
 <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>">
  <?php print $title; ?>
 </a>
</h2>
```

*Edit: Just realized, you're using Drupal 8:

For a node.html.twig you could try:

```
  {{ title_prefix }}
   {% if not page %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
     <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
    </h2>
   {% endif %}
 {{ title_suffix }}
```

Comment: `I assume, you are using Drupal 7` [he is using Drupal 8](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7ij10.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the small 8!

Comment: the question was how I can access the title of node inside the field template, not the node template