# Get entity reference node object from within rendered entity reference

Tags: theming, 8

My specific problem is similar to the one [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203618/how-to-access-the-node-title-within-a-field-template) but I am needing for it to work when the file field is within a node that is rendered within another as an entity reference.

If I use:

```
$node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
$variables['node_title'] = $node->getTitle();
```

I get the title of the main node currently being displayed and not the node of the rendered entity reference. Is there a way I can get this instead?

Comment: How is this theming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `$node` to the current request. On any node/* route that will be the node in question, not other nodes included on the page.

Since it is an entity reference field, you can access it like (for example, in a preprocess):

```
$foo_id = $node->field_reference_name->value;
$referenced_node = Node::load($foo_id);

// or
$referenced_file = File::load($foo_id);
```

If `$node->field_name->value` returns the id (node id).

However it isn't really clear if you are talking about a file, or, a node.

Comment: Im not sure but i think $node->get('fieldname')->entity works.

Comment: This worked for that specific case but didn't work when the entity reference node wasn't a field of node being referred to in the route request. Though this does indeed answer how to get the entity reference node object and has been really helpful for something else I am trying to do so thank you very much!